# how to read input and and calculate in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, json-server

i am new to reactjs. And this is my code for product price list in which i am trying to multiply data on input change, to get the total value. also i need to update the list using axios put method.

```
import './App.css';
import FormInput from './Components/FormInput';
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([])
  const [qty,setQty]=useState(0)
  const crackers = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/items")
    setList(res.data)
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    crackers()
  }, [])

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setQty({
      ...qty,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.qty
    })
    console.log(qty)
  }
  return (
    <div >
      <form>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>S.no</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Unit</th>
              <th>price</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>total</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {list.map((item) => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.unit}</td>
                <td>{item.price}</td>
                <td>
                  <FormInput type="number" name={item.name} handleChange={handleChange} value={qty}/>
                </td>
                <td>{item.price*qty}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my FormInput element.

```
const FormInput = ({name,value,handleChange,type}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <input
            type={type}
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={value[name]}
            name={name}
        />
    </div>
  )
}
export default FormInput
```

Using this code i could not multiply the product price and quantity.
could you please correct if i made any mistake, since i am new to this.

i tried to multiply the price and qty from input. but i get NaN in all total field.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in App.js :

```
import './App.css';
import FormInput from './Components/FormInput';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [qty, setQty] = useState({}); // Use an object to store quantities

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/items");
    const initialQty = {}; // Initialize quantities for each item
    res.data.forEach((item) => {
      initialQty[item.name] = 0; // Initialize quantity to 0 for each item
    });
    setQty(initialQty);
    setList(res.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setQty({
      ...qty,
      [name]: parseInt(value) || 0, // Ensure value is a number, default to 0 if not
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>S.no</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Unit</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {list.map((item) => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.unit}</td>
                <td>{item.price}</td>
                <td>
                  <FormInput
                    type="number"
                    name={item.name}
                    handleChange={handleChange}
                    value={qty[item.name]} // Use qty[item.name] to get the quantity
                  />
                </td>
                <td>{item.price * qty[item.name]}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks bro.. that's working....any advice to calculate overall total on same page?